# In clause for a list of pair of conditions

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

There is a table from where I need to fetch paginated records by applying and condition in a list of paired values, Below is the explanation

Lets say I have a class `Billoflading` and there are various fields in it
The two important fields in the table are

1. `tenant`
2. `billtype`

I have a list of pairs which contain values as

```
[
   {`tenant1`, `billtype1`},
   {`tenant2`, `billtype2`},
   {`tenant3`, `billtype3`},
   ....
  ]
```

I need a JPA query where the fetch will be like 
findByTenantAndBilltypeOrTenantAndBillTypeOr.....

in simple sql query it will be like

```
Select * from `Billoflading` where 
`tenant` = 'tenant1' and billtype = 'billtype1'
OR `tenant` = 'tenant2' and billtype = 'billtype2'
OR `tenant` = 'tenant3' and billtype = 'billtype3'
OR ......... so on..
```

I tried writing a JPA query as follows

```
Page<Billoflading> findByTenantInAndBillTypeIn(List<String> tenants, List<String> billTypes, Page page);
```

but this had crossover records as well
i.e it gave records for tenant1 and billtype2, benant2 and billtype 3 so on... which are not needed in the result set

can anyone please solve this and help me finding a simple solution like

```
Page<Billoflading> findByTenantAndBillTypeIn(Map<String, String> tenantsAndBilltyes, Page page);
```

I am also ready for the native queries in JPA all I need is there should be no crossovers as this is a very sensitive data

The other workaround I had was fetching the records and applying java 8 filters and that works but the no. of records in a page gets reduced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Section 4.6.9 of the [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html) makes it clear that this is not supported by JPQL, at least not in the form of an *in-clause*:

> **4.6.9 In Expressions**
>   The syntax for the use of the comparison operator [NOT] IN in a conditional expression is as follows:
>
> ```
> in_expression ::=
>     {state_valued_path_expression | type_discriminator} [NOT] IN
>     { ( in_item {, in_item}* ) | (subquery) | collection_valued_input_parameter } 
>
> in_item ::= literal | single_valued_input_parameter
> ```
>
> The state_valued_path_expression must have a string, numeric, date, time, timestamp, or enum value.
>
> The literal and/or input parameter values must be like the same abstract schema type of the state_valued_path_expression in type. (See Section 4.12).
>
> The results of the subquery must be like the same abstract schema type of the state_valued_path_expression in type.

It just doesn't operate on tuples.

Your best bet is probably to create a `Specification` to construct the combination of `AND` and `OR` you require. See [this blog article how to create `Specifications`](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will try with the list of criterias as well as list inside a criteria,

A quick question though, do you recommend list of criterias or list inside a criteria? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean with the two options.

Comment: Ohh, Sorry for the misunderstanding, The solution with the criteria is working and I was able to find the desired results, Thanks for all the time and valuable inputs