# JPA in clause on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa

In SQL you can match on multiple parameters with the IN statement:

```
SELECT * FROM PERSON p WHERE (p.name, p.address) in (('John', 'Fith Street'), ('Sandy', 'Second Avenue'));
```

Is it possible to create such a statement in JPA?

Answer (score 0):

Found this post: [In clause for a list of pair of conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48819996/in-clause-for-a-list-of-pair-of-conditions)

This states that it isn't supported in JPA.